# system of differential equation finding pitchfork biforcation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

[Image of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKRkm.jpg)

> \begin{align}
>  \frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} = f(x,y) &= - x+\gamma(b x+y)-\epsilon(b x+y)^3\\
>   \frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t} = g(x,y) &= - r y-\alpha b x
> \end{align}
>   Based on real data, one can assume that $\alpha < r$. We will also introduce the notation $\mu = b \gamma$. Prove then that for $\mu_0 = \frac{1}{1-\frac{\alpha}{r}}$ the system undergoes a pitchfork bifurcation, i.e. the number of equilibria changes from 1 to 3.

I can't figure out if I'm supposse to substitute $\mu$ into $dx/dt$ or if because $dy/dt$ is linear integrate in order to find $y(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, as stated, to investigate the *equilibria* of the system, in particular the number of different possible equilibria. An equilibrium is by definition constant in time, so if $(x_*,y_*)$ is an equilibrium of the system, that means that $f(x_*,y_*) = 0$ and $g(x_*,y_*)= 0$. I'm sure you can take things from here.